# Delete an Object from the H2 database by ID without autogenerated ( The given id must not be null!)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, http-delete

I made a list of rooms without an autogenerated ID because the ID is also the room number and I want to give them this number manually. But in postman, I can not delete one room from the list/database(h2). I get the Error:

```
ERROR 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!] with root cause
```

I didn't find anything for delete yet, only post requests, which work fine for me.
Class:

```java
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "roomNr")
public class Room {
    @Id
    private Integer roomNr;
```

Controller:

```
 @CrossOrigin
 @DeleteMapping("{roomNr}")
 public void deleteOneZimmer(Integer roomNr){
        roomService.deleteOneRoom(roomNr);
```

Service:

```java
public void deleteOneRoom(Integer roomNr){
        roomRep.deleteById(roomNr);
    }
```

and in postman, I get `status: 500, error: Internal Server Error`.

the path in postman is: room/1 and any other room with another ID is not working either.

This is my first post, so sorry if I am missing some info to solve that problem.

Comment: I would add logging to the controller, if the `roomNr` really gets populated as you want and also if the right method gets called at all.

Comment: can you give me a link or smth so i know what logging is? i find in google many different things. is it the same as log incoming request controller or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992216/logging-from-springmvc-controller.
i probably have to say that the entity also has a jointable with the bookings. maybe the foreign key is the problem, which is autogenarted there.

Comment: To help you better on logging, I would need to know if you use plain Spring or a complete setup with Spring Boot? And as for the joined table: did you configure that the deletions are propagated? Or what is the intended behaviour for the table with the foreign keys?

Comment: i use in the pom: spring boot starter: data-jpa, web,test,validation; lombok;h2 and plugin is maven-plugin. manytomany(cascade = cascadeType.ALL) if that is what you meant with propagated. the purpose is that one booking can have many rooms and also one room can have many bookings, just at different times.

Comment: You can add a logger to the controller class with `private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);` and then use it in the method `deleteOneZimmer` with `log.info("deleting room {}", roomNr);`. Usually you would prefer `log.debug` for this so production code will not output that, but then I would have to instruct you how to enable debug logging - too much for a single comment here ;)

Comment: thanks, i found the problem. i simple forgot the @Pathvariable in the controller. but never the less, i am sure i will need a logger in the future and will try out your method anyway. and then this will help me a lot. so thank you again.

Comment: if you fixed it, post the answer and mark it as valid, it will help future users (and you'll get some points too)

Comment: Done, will validate it tomorrow when i can. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem: I simply forgot @Pathvaribale in the Controller Class.